# How to change color of preference-headers, title

Tags: android, styles, preference-headers

I have created preference in android app along with preference-headers to categorize the preference, it works fine but now i want to change the color of the header-text.

i have tried different kind of styling approach but nothing worked

here is my preference-headers.xml code,

```java
<preference-headers  
....
    <header
        android:fragment="acr.browser.lightning.settings.fragment.GeneralSettingsFragment"
        android:title="@string/settings_general"/>
</preference-headers >
```

I expect the preference-headers title color to red but it is white
[image]